# How to import vue plugins installed with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am sorry upfront for the pretty noobie question, but I don't know how to import plugins installed with npm. I would like to use this [plugin](https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/) for Vue, I have installed it with npm, in my project, and would like to import it to my main app.js file so that I can use it in Vue.
I have tried with using the path to the file in dist folder:

```
import MaskedInput from 'node-modules/vue-masked-input/dist/MaskedInput.js'
Vue.use(MaskedInput);
```

But, that obviously didn't work, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link this is actually a component, so what you could do in your component is:

```
import MaskedInput from 'vue-masked-input'

export default {
    components: {
        MaskedInput
    }
}
```

What usually helps is by clicking through to the actual github page, and look for either an example in the README or in the actual code. In this case:

https://github.com/niksmr/vue-masked-input/blob/master/src/App.vue

There it shows you how you can use it 'in real life'

Comment: But, surely I can just import it like that, since the files there are in the same level, and in my project the file MaskedInput is in the node-modules folder, and even when I tried your suggestion it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure why downvoting is appropiate, but looking at the github page it clearly says: import MaskedInput from 'vue-masked-input' 
... 
components: { 
  MaskedInput 
} So difference is you import it as `vue-masked-input`

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing that out, I have done like you said, but I am not sure if I did that correctly, I have added to my current component the code you suggested, but then I have got a new error: ```Attributes "v-model", "mask", "placeholder" are ignored on component <masked-input> because the component is a fragment instance:```

Comment: I will just make another question about the new problem, and mark your answer as the correct one